# Date/Time formatting Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to convert following date/time: **"04-26-2018 10:17 AM"** to this format: **"2018-04-26T10:17"**

here's my code:

```
let myDateString = "04-26-2018 10:17 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a"

let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myDateString)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
let somedateString = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate)
```

The output for somedateString is **"2018-04-26T00:17"** which is incorrect.. is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: CST, how timezone matters here?

Comment: Are you not working with times? Really you should be using two date formatters here rather than one and changing it. Try using `hh:mm` in the first instance. `hh` denotes twelve hour time notation. `HH` is 24 hour notation.

Comment: I did see your question. In fact, I would have had to see it in order to add a comment. The fact that my comment is indeed about time shows that I read your question and was trying to establish some details about what might be causing this problem. From your latest comment I see that you are not particularly interested in helping me help you :) Best of luck :)

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks your suggestion worked HH needed to be hh in this case.

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry for confusion I deleted my other comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need correct `DateFormatter` this `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a` to `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a`

```
let myDateString = "04-26-2018 10:17 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"

let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myDateString)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"
let somedateString = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate)
```

Comment: 04-26-2018 10:17 AM on this date the time was in 12 hours Format bus you taking as HH means 24 hour

Comment: First the second date format is wrong. You are using hh (12 hour) without am pm. Btw when parsing fixed date format string you need to set the date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: thanks, locale not needed but if you want to convert date or time in specific timeZone then is will needed

Comment: The locale is required you should take a look at Parsing Date Strings https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: yes but not need to set because when we convert format it make the conversion with same locale

Comment: You should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a locale that's specifically **designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.** en_US_POSIX is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior, but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (en_US_POSIX works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169912/discussion-between-harshad-pipaliya-and-leo-dabus).